# Django's TemplateResponse looking in the wrong directory for templates

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-admin

File Tree (Rough Example)

```
project/
    project/
        .
        .
    project_admin/
        admin.py
    app/
        .
        .
```

project_admin/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.urls import path


class BookrAdmin(admin.AdminSite):
    logout_template = 'admin/logout.html'

    def profile_view(self, request):
        request.current_app = self.name
        context = self.each_context(request)
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'admin/admin_profile.html', context)

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        url_patterns = [path("admin_profile", self.profile_view)]
        return urls + url_patterns
```

project/settings.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
.
.
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I am a goober and updating this question. I realized my initial post was wrong.

Here is my error.

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/admin_profile
Raised by:  django.contrib.admin.sites.catch_all_view

 Using the URLconf defined in bookr.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    accounts/
    accounts/profile/ [name='profile']
    admin/ [name='index']
    admin/ login/ [name='login']
    admin/ logout/ [name='logout']
    admin/ password_change/ [name='password_change']
    admin/ password_change/done/ [name='password_change_done']
    admin/ autocomplete/ [name='autocomplete']
    admin/ jsi18n/ [name='jsi18n']
    admin/ r/<int:content_type_id>/<path:object_id>/ [name='view_on_site']
    admin/ auth/group/
    admin/ auth/user/
    admin/ reviews/review/
    admin/ ^(?P<app_label>auth|reviews)/$ [name='app_list']
    admin/ (?P<url>.*)$

The current path, admin/admin_profile, matched the last one.
```

So I feel this has something to do with `project_admin/admin.py` file. For whatever reason for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/[this can be anything]` and I still get the same error with a matching path. I'm not sure where to go from here. I don't get a trackback because nothing a failing. It just wont load by `admin_profile.html` which extends the default django `admin/index.html`.

---Reason for Original Edit---
The reason why I thought `TemplateResponse` was pulling from the wrong directory was because I had my pycharm configured to think the wrong template directory was my root template directory. This has now been fixed.

---Answer---
`return urls + url_patterns`->`return url_patterns + urls`

Comment: Have you added your app to your apps?

Comment: @AaronCloud I have

Comment: Do me a favor, try just running 

'DIR': ['templates']

get ride of the base_dir

Comment: @AaronCloud Nope. I made sure I was logged in as admin because it is an admin page, but still nothing.

Comment: Maybe returning things like: `return TemplateResponse(request, 'admin/admin_profile.html', context)` like in Django doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/template-response/

Comment: @Danny I've tried. Still not working. I'm just at a loss. It seems like path matches ```The current path, admin/admin_profile, matched the last one.``` but I still get a 404.

Comment: Can you add the error you’re getting? Are you just missing the “.html” at the end of your template path?

Comment: @getup8 I edited the question. I haven't been drinking enough coffee. I think I need to register an instance of the class, but this I feel that's really just if I am using an admin model not site. -- Going forward -- the reason I thought ```TemplateResponse``` was pulling from the wrong file was because pycharm thought the template file in my app was the root template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is that you have added your url pattern after the result of `get_urls`. The problem is that since Django 3.2 (new in this version) at the end of the list returned by `get_urls` there is a url pattern that will catch *all* possible urls and route them to a `catch_all_view`, and hence since it is before your pattern in the list that view is used for your url and you get an error. This can be seen from the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/775f7506d7fbabf79d8bdec4ccf039ce2870fe70/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L293-L294):

> ```
> if self.final_catch_all_view:
>     urlpatterns.append(re_path(r'(?P<url>.*)$', wrap(self.catch_all_view)))
> ```

This behaviour as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.AdminSite.final_catch_all_view) can be removed by setting `final_catch_all_view` to `False` in your admin site. But the documentation also recommends not doing that since it protects your from enumeration attacks. Instead what you should do is to add your url pattern at the *start* of your list:

```
class BookrAdmin(admin.AdminSite):
    logout_template = 'admin/logout.html'

    def profile_view(self, request):
        request.current_app = self.name
        context = self.each_context(request)
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'admin/admin_profile.html', context)

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        url_patterns = [path("admin_profile/", self.profile_view)]
        return url_patterns + urls  # Keep your patterns first in the list so they don't get caught by the catch all view
```

Comment: Thank you! I literally just found this out and edited my question at the same time you answered.